# Initiate a call via REST API and then make other side call back another number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to find out if we would be able to implement the following flow with Twilio:

- a user in our web application presses a button on a web page, which triggers a call to a Java BE service
- at this point the BE service has knowledge of phone number A (the number of the person the user wants to get in contact with), and phone number B (the user's phone number). Both are just ordinary real world phone numbers
- the BE service then makes a call to the Twilio API for establishing an outbound voice call to phone A with a voice message
- when party A picks up, a message (something like "xyz wants to get in contact with you, please press '1' to initiate a call") will be played
- when party A presses the right button he should be connected to phone number B by placing an outbound call to B

End effect is that a phone call is established between phone A and phone B, without our app ever being in the picture (other than sending the inital voice message)

Is this possible with Twilio (or any other third party service)?

Comment: This is certainly possible. However, I'm not sure if I understand the exact scenario. Can you describe who party A and party B is in the bullet points?
Depending in the scenario a [whisper call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/call-whisper) or a [conference call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-create-conference-calls) with multiple parties might be the way to go.

Comment: Party A and Party B could really be any two phone numbers that should get tied together into a call. I updated the description to make it a little more clear, hope it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Then a conference call is probably the right choice for you